# How to add DLL to GAC and embed with exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, assemblies

I need the `C#` code to add the assemblies to the `GAC`. Does anybody know how to add DLLs to `GAC` using `C#`?

**EDIT:**
I am trying to load a dll using bytes in a window application. As some of the dll file loads properly in my application but when I am trying to load the assembly (Microsoft_DirectX_AudioVideoPlayback.dll) it is giving me error of badImage exception. Basically I just need to load the assembly from bytes array using the following method.

```
byte[] ByteArray = Resource1.Microsoft_DirectX_AudioVideoPlayback;
 Assembly.Load(ByteArray );
```

where BytesArray is the assembly bytes array.

I am getting following lines as an error.

An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
System.badImageformat exception :`{"An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"}`

Comment: This is something you would do as part of your installer rather than something the application would do when running.

Comment: @Belogix: No; it's something you wouldn't do at all.

Comment: Let me explain you bit more. I have created a .exe file that Includes all these things In the form of bytes. So when I run this exe It should automatically Opens a video . So please suggest me any solution.

Comment: @v Code formatting is not supposed to be used to add emphasis. It is meant for code. Also, code requests are generally frowned upon on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @MikroDel: i am working on it, i will do it don't worry.

Comment: @MikroDel: i tried alot but can't find the proper solution i want, i posted the problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910877/load-dll-from-resource-file

Comment: Why do you duplicate your questions? If you have tried somethins from answers posted to your questions an it doesnt work - show it here - update or first question with new information. But dont duplicate your question.

Comment: okay thanks, i thought its bit diffrent questions

Comment: Now it is a different question. You have commented "i tried alot but can't find the proper solution i want, i posted the problem here ..."

Comment: If you edit is also about "How to add dll in GAC using c#" - than it is right place here and you can delete your second question... If it has nothing to do with adding DLL in GAC using C# - than second question you have created is OK, but delete this edit of your first question.

Comment: @MikroDel okay i will delete second question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31167/discussion-between-mikrodel-and-vijay-singh-rana)

Answer (score 5):

```
Publish publish = new Publish();

publish.GacInstall(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("MyAssembly.dll"));
```

**Namespace**:  System.EnterpriseServices.Internal

**Assembly**:  System.EnterpriseServices (in System.EnterpriseServices.dll)

Comment: You need an instance.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enterpriseservices.internal.publish.gacinstall.aspx

Comment: @SLaks what instance do you mean?

Comment: An instance of the `Publish` class.

Comment: You also need to mention which assembly and namespace to reference.

Comment: It is very important; otherwise, people will have no idea how to use this.

Answer (score 3):

No; you don't need to add anything to the GAC.

You can simply call `Assembly.Load()` to load the assemblies directly from the byte arrays embedded in your file.
Note that you will need to do that before the JITer encounters any types from those assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

When you include your video file you have to include it as a "Embedded Resource". 
If you do not know how to do it here are the steps.

1. Add your video file to the project.
2. Click on the video file. Go to properties.
3. Select build action "Embedded Resource"

Then use below class to retrieve the video as a byte array. I am sure you can take care of the rest.

```
    using System.IO;
    using System.Reflection;

    namespace MyProject.Video
    {
        class MyVideoClass
        {
            private const string videoExtract = "MyProject.Video.MyVideo.dat";      

            public byte[] GetStream()
            {
                try
                {
                    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    Stream sourceStream = null;

                    sourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(videoExtract); 

                    if (sourceStream != null) sourceStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

                    return memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
                catch
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```